# Iterating and parsing in lines of text file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have day one with Matlab and I am trying to figure out how to inport data from my .log file.

So a single line looks like this:

> 123456.99 :: working completed: result=0 , data ="{"day":"monday", "breakfast":"sandwich"}"

I have opend the file with fileread() command.

But, I am interested only from the part after data ={} where the data there could be saved as JSON and later easily used. I dont know how to iterate and parse over the whole file?

I have tried googleing it, but the solutions there seem too complicated and not understandable. Could some one give me hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fileread](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fileread.html) to read the file:

```
>> rawData = fileread('mydocument.txt');
```

[regexp](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to parse the data:

```
>> myJson = regexp(rawData,'data ="({[^}]+})','tokens','once');
```

[jsondecode](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jsondecode.html) to decode the json:

```
>> jsondecode(myJson{:})
   ans = 

   struct with fields:

          day: 'monday'
    breakfast: 'sandwich'
```

Comment: Hey I have marked your answer as solution since it answered my question. I have a further one if you could help. fileread reads only one line, if I wanted to do to the same only with a text file that had a lot of lines, bsc if I had to iterate is there a smooth way to do it?